# Activity Navigation advice please

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, state

Ok . . . I have read hours upon hours of advice and forums and developer pages to no conclusive answer.

what I have: is an app with 8 activities and each has a slightly different set of buttons to navigate to some of the other activities. Each activity has multiple forms of data collection, ultimately ending in an e-mail intent which collects all application UI data.

Problem: I cant seem to find the proper way to use the navigation buttons in conjuction with onSavedInstanceState so that no matter what, everytime an activity is started it will appear with any and all data the user has inputed(sp?) thus far, during this instance of the application. I dont want to save data beyond closing the app. I do want the user to be able to navigate back and forth as much as necessary within the activities without losing data until the app closes.

This is what I have:

Activity A: has buttons to: Activity B, C, D, E, and F(F=email intent)

Activity B: has buttons to: Activity G, and A
Activity G: has buttons to: Activity B, and A

Activity C: has buttons to: Activity H, I, and A
Activity H: has buttons to: Activity C, I, and A
Activity I: has buttons to: Activity H, I, and A

Activity D: has button to: Activity A

Activity E: has button to: Activity A

Is there a better way to set up my navigation? (this is optimal for the context I am fairly sure)

And what is the proper launch mode/Flags/savedinstancestate and whatever to achieve proper result? I can explain elaborate as much as needed.

I am aware I need to save the data the problem is setting up the activities so that the navigation buttons i have put in each activity always open activity showing all previously saved data (in the current task instance)

I have all activites set to launchMode:singleTask, I have not manually coded any flagsand I have set up onsavedinstance properly but something as simple as: Activity B-> Activity A-> Activity B (using only my buttons) Activity B saves nothing after going to A and back again (again I am not using back key, I am using my navigation buttons in the layout) How can I fix this??

Oddly tho Activity A DOES retain memory but none of the other activities do

Comment: Would it simplify matters to save Application wide state in the Application Context? Then each activity could read and write to the Application Context. The downside is that all instances of an Activity would share the same state. I posted some code at http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you're using singleTask?
Aren't you looking for

```
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

?

Comment: Thank you so much ... this worked! ended a two week search for an answer . . .I would up vote if i could

Comment: Thanks. I'll recommend you to [read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html). It'll save your time in future :)